# Cisco PIX 515 doesn't seem to be passing traffic through according to static route

Tags: static-routes, cisco-pix

Ok, so I am having a spot of bother with a Cisco PIX515, I have posted the current running config below, now I am no cisco expert by any means although I can do basic stuff with them, now I am having trouble with traffic sent from the outside to address: 10.75.32.25 it just doesn't appear to be going anywhere.

Now this firewall is deep inside a private network, with an upstream firewall that we don't manage. I have spoken to the people that look after that firewall and they say they they have traffic routing to 10.75.32.21 and 10.75.32.25 and thats it (although there is a website that runs from the server 172.16.102.5 which (if my understanding is correct) gets traffic via 10.75.32.23.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as to me it should all just work, but its not (obviously if the config is all correct then there could be a problem with the web server that we are trying to access on 10.75.32.25, although the users say that they can get to it internally (172.16.102.8) which is even more confusing)

```
PIX Version 6.3(3)  
interface ethernet0 auto  
interface ethernet1 auto  
interface ethernet2 auto  
nameif ethernet0 outside security0  
nameif ethernet1 inside security100  
nameif ethernet2 academic security50  
fixup protocol dns maximum-length 512  
fixup protocol ftp 21  
fixup protocol h323 h225 1720  
fixup protocol h323 ras 1718-1719  
fixup protocol http 80  
fixup protocol rsh 514  
fixup protocol rtsp 554  
fixup protocol sip 5060  
fixup protocol sip udp 5060  
fixup protocol skinny 2000  
fixup protocol smtp 25  
fixup protocol sqlnet 1521  
fixup protocol tftp 69  
names  
name 195.157.180.168 outsideNET  
name 195.157.180.170 globalNAT  
name 195.157.180.174 gateway  
name 195.157.180.173 Mail-Global  
name 172.30.31.240 Mail-Local 
name 10.75.32.20 outsideIF  
name 82.219.210.17 frogman1  
name 212.69.230.79 frogman2  
name 78.105.118.9 frogman3  
name 172.16.0.0 acadNET  
name 172.16.100.254 acadIF  
access-list acl_outside permit icmp any any echo-reply  
access-list acl_outside permit icmp any any unreachable  
access-list acl_outside permit icmp any any time-exceeded  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.22 eq smtp  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.22 eq 8383  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.22 eq 8385    
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.22 eq 8484  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.22 eq 8485  
access-list acl_outside permit ip any host 10.75.32.30  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.25 eq https  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.25 eq www  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.23 eq www  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.23 eq https  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman1 host 10.75.32.23 eq ssh  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman2 host 10.75.32.23 eq ssh  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman3 host 10.75.32.23 eq ssh  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.23 eq 2001  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman1 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8441  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman2 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8441  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman3 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8441  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman1 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8442  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman2 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8442  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman3 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8442  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman1 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8443   
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman2 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8443  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp host frogman3 host 10.75.32.24 eq 8443  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.23 eq smtp  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.23 eq ssh  
access-list acl_outside permit tcp any host 10.75.32.24 eq ssh  
access-list acl_acad permit icmp any any echo-reply  
access-list acl_acad permit icmp any any unreachable  
access-list acl_acad permit icmp any any time-exceeded  
access-list acl_acad permit tcp any 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 eq www  
access-list acl_acad deny tcp any any eq www  
access-list acl_acad permit tcp any 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 eq https  
access-list acl_acad permit tcp any 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 eq 8080  
access-list acl_acad permit tcp host 172.16.102.5 host 10.64.1.115 eq smtp  
pager lines 24  
logging console debugging  
mtu outside 1500  
mtu inside 1500  
mtu academic 1500  
ip address outside outsideIF 255.255.252.0  
no ip address inside  
ip address academic acadIF 255.255.0.0  
ip audit info action alarm  
ip audit attack action alarm  
pdm history enable  
arp timeout 14400  
global (outside) 1 10.75.32.21  
nat (academic) 1 acadNET 255.255.0.0 0 0  
static (academic,outside) 10.75.32.22 Mail-Local netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0  
static (academic,outside) 10.75.32.30 172.30.30.36 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0  
static (academic,outside) 10.75.32.23 172.16.102.5 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0  
static (academic,outside) 10.75.32.24 172.16.102.6 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0  
static (academic,outside) 10.75.32.25 172.16.102.8 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0  
access-group acl_outside in interface outside  
access-group acl_acad in interface academic  
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.75.32.1 1  
timeout xlate 3:00:00  
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 rpc 0:10:00 h225 1:00:00  
timeout h323 0:05:00 mgcp 0:05:00 sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00  
timeout uauth 0:05:00 absolute  
aaa-server TACACS+ protocol tacacs+  
aaa-server RADIUS protocol radius  
aaa-server LOCAL protocol local  
snmp-server host outside 172.31.10.153  
snmp-server host outside 172.31.10.154  
snmp-server host outside 172.31.10.155  
no snmp-server location  
no snmp-server contact    
snmp-server community CPQ_HHS  
no snmp-server enable traps  
floodguard enable  
telnet 172.30.31.0 255.255.255.0 academic  
telnet timeout 5  
ssh timeout 5  
console timeout 0  
terminal width 120  
Cryptochecksum:hi2u  
: end  
PIX515#
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the config was good, the server was responding albiet very slowly, and intermittently.